# Результат запроса mysql в таблицу письма

Tags: php, mysql, email

Есть такой код

```
     <?php

    include('config.php');

    $today = date ("d");
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT fio, doljnost, podr, bdate FROM dnuhi WHERE bdate LIKE '".$today."%' ");

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $fio=$rows['fio'];
    $doljnost=$rows['doljnost'];
    $podr=$rows['podr'];
    echo $fio." - ".$podr." - ".$doljnost;
    echo "<br>";
    }

    $to  = 'qqq@qqq.ru';
    $subject = 'Дни рождения!';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
      <p>Дни рождения</p>
      <table>
Вот сюда нужно вывести результаты в виде:
Иванов Иван Иванович - Астрахань - Кадровик
Петров Петр Николаевич - Владивосток - Менеджер
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: mail@qqq.ru <mail@qqq.ru>' . "\r\n";
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Не могу разобраться как из результата запроса вставить в тело письма. Что-бы все это ушло одним письмом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собирайте строки для таблицы сразу в цикле:

...

```
$message_rows = "";  
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {  
    $message_rows .= "<tr><td>".$rows['fio']."-".$rows['podr']."-".$rows['doljnost']."</td></tr>";  
}
```

Далее указывайте в $message переменную строк

```
  $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
      <p>Дни рождения</p>
      <table>
      '.$message_rows.'  
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
```